# Pass different methods as parameter to invoke by method name

Tags: c#, delegates

I have several methods in a *Util* class with different return types and different parameters, f.e:

```
int RealMethodToExecute(int i, string s) { ... }
```

Those methods must be invoked in the ui thread and the call would look something like that:

```
int x = (int)InvokeControl.Invoke("Util.RealMethodToExecute");
```

Because in my opinion using the method names as string is not really pretty, i thought at the following solution:

```
public int WrappedRealMethodToExecute(int i, string s)
{
    return InvokeMethod(Util.RealMethodToExecute, i, s);
}

private static T InvokeMethod<T>(Func<int, string, T> func, params object[] p)
{            
    return (T)InvokeControl.Invoke(func.Method.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + func.Method.Name, p);
}
```

The problem now is that *InvokeMethod* only acceppts methods with an int and a string parameter and a return value but i have different methods which i want to execute.

I dont want to overload *InvokeMethod*. I just need the full qualified name of the function to execute it.

Any ideas??

edit: extended example with parameters

Comment: Using the *name* around for invoke is a pretty horrible approach, but: can I clarify - you say about parameters; if you *did* supply a method that took parameters, where do you expect it to get the argument values from?

Comment: What i do not understand is, if you can pass a delegate around, why not invoke the normal method anyway ?

Comment: @b_meyer I'd go back a level; *why* are we having a "run this synchronously for me" method... why not just *run the method directly?* - i.e. `int x = Util.RealMethodToExecute();`

Comment: @b_meyer its a little bit more complicated, because the normal methods have a other signature than i show here (it is an extension for a gui testing framework) and i dont wanted to make the example more complicated

Comment: @MarcGravell because i have the function to invoke in the ui thread of the application under test

Comment: @stefantinger right; by why do that *by name*? What you are trying to do sounds like a standard use of *just a plain old delegate*. Just *invoke the delegate*

Comment: @MarcGravell The invoke method only allow passing the function name  (string) and not passing a delegate

Answer (score 0):

Fankly, this might as well be just:

```
private static object InvokeMethod(Delegate method, params object[] args)
{            
    return InvokeControl.Invoke(method, args);
}
```

where `InvokeControl.Invoke` uses (to get to the UI thread):

```
someControl.Invoke(method, args);
```

Comment: Already commented above: The invoke method only allow passing the function name (string) and not passing a delegate (unfortunately)

Comment: @stefantinger that sounds bizarre, but I guess you just have to do what you can